# Angularjs directives isolated scope + one-way data-binding not working for objects?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-directive

I have created a custom directive which has two values. first is config object and second is data object. I modify this config and data objects inside my directive which is reflecting it in parent scope. Which is causing me error when I have to use directive multiple times.

I followed https://umur.io/angularjs-directives-using-isolated-scope-with-attributes/ and I am using isolated scope.

I want one way data binding for objects in isolated scope. Whatever I change in directive function it should not reflect in the parent scope.

below is scope of directive.

```
scope: {
    config: "&config",
    dataObj: "&dataObj"
}
```

here is how I access it in the link function of directive

```
var config = scope.config();
var dataObj= scope.dataObj();
```

I am assuming that pass by reference is happening here.

I am adding JSbin. check the console the value of object is changing and reflecting in parent scope.

https://jsbin.com/vagowe/edit?html,js,output

Comment: So what is the specific problem? Please show all relevant code and create a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue) demo that replicates issue

Comment: @charlietfl I have added the demo. hope you understand my problem

Comment: You have to use `=` two-way binding to pass objects to a directive.

Comment: @ThinkingMedia I am passing object to directive.. then I am modifying that object.. I dont want to reflect that object changes in parent scope... Two way data binding will reflect changes to parent scope. which I don't want. I want one way data binding of objects..

Comment: `var x = angular.copy($scope.config);`

Comment: @ThinkingMedia Is the correct way to do that ? Angular directive don't have anything to handle objects ?

Comment: Keep in mind that directives are template based. Their parameters are just attributes. It's not user friendly if you have to pass objects, but sometimes it's necessary for complex directives. If all you need is width and height, then just have two attributes for width and height.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92270/discussion-between-murli2308-and-thinkingmedia).

Comment: You don't want one-way binding, you simply want a copy of the object. That's two different things. And it's not an Angular issue either. It's the same situation as passing arguments to a regular JavaScript function. Two-way binding is not the problem here.

Comment: `@` is for binding interpolated text, not one-way binding! With Angular 1.5 there is one-way binding with `<`.

Comment: @Aides I was using Angular 1.3 at that time. You can add answer there is new or perfect answer for above question with new version of Angular 1.x.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

passing text is `one-way binding(@)` and passing object is `two-way binding(=)`

passing object as text

```
<custom-directive config="{{config}}"></custom-directive>
```

scope in directive

```js
scope: {
  config: "@"
}
```

converting the string back to object in link

```
var config = angular.fromJson(scope.config);
```

Comment: great its working.. so we are passing object as stringifying object here and in directive parsing string to object right ?

Comment: true, instead of accessing as function(&) can access parent scope object (it two-way binding).

Comment: is this the proper and only way to solve this problem ?

Comment: I see this as better way, because there is no way to manipulate the parent scope object, if you use = or & there is always a chance of modifying the parent scope object

Comment: There is now a one-way binding as well

```scope: {
    config: '<'
}```

Answer (score 6):

You are correct, the issue is that your JavaScript objects are being passed by reference. Using a one-way binding copies the reference, but the reference will still point to the same object.

My impression from the [Angular docs for directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-) has always been:

- The '@' binding is intended for interpolated strings
- The '=' binding is intended for structured data that should be shared between scopes
- The '&' binding is intended for repeatedly executing an expression that is bound to the parent scope

If you want to treat the bound object from the parent as immutable, you can create a deep copy the objects inside your link code using [angular.copy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy):

```
var config = angular.copy(scope.config());
var dataObj = angular.copy(scope.dataObj());
```

Alternatively, you can use a two-way binding for this and copy the object in the same way:

```
scope: {
    config: "=",
    dataObj: "="
}

// ...
// Inside the link function of the directive.
// Note that scope.config and scope.dataObj are no longer functions!

var config = angular.copy(scope.config);
var dataObj = angular.copy(scope.dataObj);
```

Comment: I solved a la `$scope.config = angular.copy($scope.config__);` in my directive CONTROLLER. makes more sense I think and the copied array stays.

Comment: For  a directive, I find `angular.copy()` makes more sense than `angular.fromJson()` for one way binding.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing would be to use the below statement inside the directive/component-

```
scope.config = angular.copy(scope.config);
```