# Controller scope in directive is not updated

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I have next function where I do async request to server and then applying returned value to complex controller object:

```
this.createIdleTimeWidget = function () {
        var $this = this;
        $dashboardFactory.getIdleTimeCurrentStatus().then(function (response) {
            var widgetId = $commonUtils.generateQuickGuid();
            Object.keys(response.data).forEach(function (item) {
                if (!hasOwnProperty.call($this.widgets, widgetId)) {
                    $this.widgets[widgetId] = {};
                }
                var obj = $dashboardFactory.genereteIdleStatusObject(item, response.data[item]);
                Object.defineProperty($this.widgets[widgetId], Object.keys(obj)[0], {
                    value: obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]],
                    writable: true,
                    enumerable: true,
                    configurable: true
                });

            });
            $this.dashboardOptions.addWidget({
                name: 'idleTime',
                id: widgetId
            });


        });
    }
```

Add widget invokes directive with next :

```
 return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            scope: {
                type: '@',
                timewidgetfor: '@',
                widgetid:'@'
            },       
            controller: 'dashboardController',       
            link: function ($scope, element, iAttrs, controller) {         

                var date = new Date();
                var seconds = date.getSeconds();
                var minutes = date.getMinutes();
                var hours = date.getHours();

            function compileTemplate() {
                var template = $templateCache.get('clockWidgetTemplate.html');
                var interpolatedTemplate = $interpolate(template)($scope);
                element.html($interpolate(template)($scope));
                var elem = angular.element(document.querySelector('#' + iAttrs.id + ' .inner-box'));
                return elem;
            };
....
```

Template looks like:

```
 $templateCache.put('clockTemplate.html',
       '<div class="clock-container"><div ngx-timer widgetId={{widget.id}} timeWidgetFor="now" type="Hours" class="box hours" id="hours"></div> <div widgetId={{widget.id}}  timeWidgetFor="now" ngx-timer type="Minutes" class="box minutes" id="minutes"></div><div ngx-timer widgetId={{widget.id}}  timeWidgetFor="now" type="Seconds" class="box seconds" id="seconds"></div></div></div>'
     + '<div class="clock-container"><div ngx-timer widgetId={{widget.id}} timeWidgetFor="today" type="Hours" class="box hours" id="hours"></div>   <div widgetId={{widget.id}}  timeWidgetFor="today" ngx-timer type="Minutes" class="box minutes" id="minutes"></div><div ngx-timer widgetId={{widget.id}}  timeWidgetFor="today" type="Seconds" class="box seconds" id="seconds"></div></div></div>'
     + '<div class="clock-container"><div ngx-timer widgetId={{widget.id}} timeWidgetFor="week" type="Hours" class="box hours" id="hours"></div>    <div  widgetId={{widget.id}} timeWidgetFor="week" ngx-timer type="Minutes" class="box minutes" id="minutes"></div><div ngx-timer widgetId={{widget.id}}  timeWidgetFor="week" type="Seconds" class="box seconds" id="seconds"></div></div></div>'
     + '<div class="clock-container"><div ngx-timer widgetId={{widget.id}} timeWidgetFor="month" type="Hours" class="box hours" id="hours"></div>   <div  widgetId={{widget.id}} timeWidgetFor="month" ngx-timer type="Minutes" class="box minutes" id="minutes"></div><div ngx-timer widgetId={{widget.id}} timeWidgetFor="month" type="Seconds" class="box seconds" id="seconds"></div></div></div>');//<div ngx-timer type="AMPM" class="box ampm" id="ampm">
$templateCache.put('clockWidgetTemplate.html', '<div class="inner-box"> <span class="top">{{current}}</span><span class="top-next">{{next}}</span><span class="bottom-next">{{next}}</span> <span class="bottom">{{current}}</span> </div>');
```

However, `controller.widgets` in directive is empty object while in controller itself it is defined well.
[image]
[image]
I use controlllerAs syntax in my controller. I also tried $apply() method, still no result.

Working plunkr:[Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/fPY0R0TQXaqw4N3pzLpc)

What I am missing?

Comment: How you are using directive? can you add template?

Comment: @AvneshShakya The question was updated

Comment: First, have you tried adding console.log() and seeing what gets resolved and what does not? Second, instead of having the $dashboardFactory call as it is, put it all in a function, call it and console.log it out to see if it's getting what you expect. Third, initialize $this.widgets = []; after your var $this = this; line, see if that helps.

Comment: Problem could be attributed to the fact that code is 3.1k+ lines in length.  At the very least, a single document that is that long is much harder to debug as you are finding out right now.  If your files are over 300 lines long, you are using Angular incorrectly....

Answer (score -1):

You are using one way binding by using `@` in `directive`.

so try to bind attribute with `{{}}` for `@` like this:

```
<div class="clock-container">
   <div ngx-timer widgetId={{widget.id}} timeWidgetFor="{{now}}" type="{{hours}}" class="box hours" id="hours"></div>
</div>
```

See different use of one-way binding(`@`), two-way binding(`=`) and event binding(`&`) in this [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/avnesh2/fzyo5p0t/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=fzyo5p0t)

Comment: Thanks for help, but my problem not with isolated scope, but with controller scope. See I attached PS for more simple understanding

Comment: @ is not a one way binding. It's a text binding.

Comment: @FrederikPrijck: Yeah for text but  please check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33126555/angularjs-directives-isolated-scope-one-way-data-binding-not-working-for-objec  Hope this will clear about the same.

Comment: It's still not a one way binding. Read https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component and look for the part:  'The < symbol denotes one-way bindings'. Also have a look at: http://prntscr.com/drct79 , which is a screenshot from the docs.

Comment: check this jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/avnesh2/fzyo5p0t/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=fzyo5p0t  and play arround and see why it's one-way binding

Comment: It's a text binding, which only works oneway. But it's not a one-way binding, that's the '<'. Take some time to read the links I pasted.